# Should I use variance or standard deviation as weights to combine independent measurements?

Tags: probability, estimation, measurement-error

I've got a set of N independent measurements that I'd like to do a weighted average on to get one, hopefully better, measurement.  I've got a variance measure for each measurement, would it be more appropriate to use the inverse of the variance or the inverse of the standard deviation as my weights?